# Select a tableRow within a TableLayout Dynamically

Tags: android, xamarin.android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm creating a Tablelayout with many TableRows dynamically, for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<cont; i++)
                { 
                     id[i] = customers[i].CustomerNumber;

                     //Create a new row to be added.
                     tr = new TableRow(this);

                     //Create text views to be added to the row.
                     tv = new TextView(this);

                     //Put the data into the text view by passing it to a user defined function createView()
                     createView(tr, tv, id[i].ToString());


                     //Add the new row to our tableLayout tl
                     tl.AddView(tr);
                }
```

And this is the createView code:

```
private void createView(TableRow tr, TextView t, String viewdata) {

        t.SetText(viewdata, TextView.BufferType.Editable);

       //adjust the porperties of the textView

       //t.SetLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //You have to use Android.Graphics.Color not System.ConsoleColor;
        t.SetTextColor(Color.Blue);
        t.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Cyan); 
        t.SetPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);

        tr.SetPadding(0, 1, 0, 1); 
        tr.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black); 

        tr.AddView(t); // add TextView to row.

   }
```

My issue is that I want to select from the TableLayout that contains everything in a single row to be able to select and respond a click event in order to use it for further purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code as for making TableRow Clickable set `tr.setClickable(true)` and add a `setOnClickListener`:

```
    private void createView(TableRow tr, TextView t, String viewdata) {

        t.SetText(viewdata, TextView.BufferType.Editable);

       //adjust the porperties of the textView

       //t.SetLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //You have to use Android.Graphics.Color not System.ConsoleColor;
        t.SetTextColor(Color.Blue);
        t.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Cyan); 
        t.SetPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);

        tr.SetPadding(0, 1, 0, 1); 
        tr.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black); 
        tr.setClickable(true);

        tr.setOnClickListener(tablerowOnClickListener);//add OnClickListener Here

        tr.AddView(t); // add TextView to row.


   }
private OnClickListener tablerowOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //GET TEXT HERE
            String currenttext = ((TextView)v).getText().toString());
        }
    };
```

Comment: How can i get the id of the Row?

Comment: you are setting row id or not?

Comment: if you have still problem then tell me i will try to help u?

Answer (score 1):

Set on click listener on table row.

```
    tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //TODO:
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something cool and its working fine...

```
TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);

....

TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
tr1.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



TextView textview1 = new TextView(this);
textview1.setText(etFirstname.getText());
textview1.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
textview1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
tr1.addView(textview1);

TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
textview2.setText(etAge.getText());
//textview2.setText(etAge.getText());
textview2.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
textview2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
textview2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
tr1.addView(textview2);



tr1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow tr1=(TableRow)v;
        TextView tv1= (TextView)tr1.getChildAt(0);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tv1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});


tl.addView(tr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /************ if table row is dynamic then this method else method 2 is perfect************/
//if we want to applay listener on dynamic tablerow then use this
//sure that perfect 
 TablRowe tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setClickable(true);
tr.setId(100);// if in loop then add 1 counter with 100 like (100+counter) at end count++ it
 tr.setOnClickListener(this);
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
{
        switch (v.getId())
         {
         case 100: 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
             break;

         case 101:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "101", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             break;
}
/************************** for simple like this ************************/
   TableRow row1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row1);
row1.setonClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v)
{
switch (v.getId())
         {
         case R.id.row1: 
           // do work
             break;
          }        
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to document the reason you supplied this code as an answer.  Why is it correct; how is it different?

Comment: i thik that is perfect